# ReactJs in CEFSharp save state and restore at startup

Tags: reactjs, cefsharp

I am currently writing a ReactJS UI for my c# Project. It will run in a CEFSharp control.

Now I try to save the state of a Reacj object whenever the state is changed. 
When the c# programm is (re-)started the saved state should be restored in the page.

What is working so far:
Transmitting the state and saving it in c# is working:

```
exportState(){
    if(navigator.userAgent === 'CEF')
    {
      let jsonstate = JSON.stringify(this.state.Fenster);
      window.nativeHost.kontrolstate(jsonstate);
    }
  }
```

Fenster is an array of an own defined object.

To be able to push the saved state back to the react component I have created an ref:

```
<Kontrolle ref={(kont) => {window.Kontrolle = kont}} />
```

So I can call the procedures of component Kontrolle via a javascript call in CEFSharp.

To restore the state I call this procedure:

```
jsontostate(jsonstring){
    var fen = jsonstring;
    let fenster = this.state.Fenster;

    for (var i=0; i<fen.length;i++) {
      var f = fen[i];
      let index = fenster.findIndex(x => x.id === f.id);
      fenster[index].colum = f.colum;
      fenster[index].offen = f.offen;
      fenster[index].sort = f.sort;
    }

    this.setState({Fenster: fenster});
    this.render();
  }
```

It looks like working perfecly.
The state is updated correctly.
Also when I check the state in the debug console of CEFSharp it looks correctly.
There is also no error displayed in the console.

What is not working:
The state has influence to the page.
After calling the procedure the page is not rendered newly.
So the state and page are not in line.
I already have tried to force a render.
Without success.

Where is my mistake?
Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason by myself.
I did implement the component Kontrolle twice.
One with ref one without ref.
I checked the rendered UI on the wrong implementation.
So, my own mistake.
The code I have posted work fine.

Thanks to all.